# Why ```token_sort_ratio()``` is not working?

Tags: python, fuzzy-logic, fuzzywuzzy

I have two strings as follows -

```
key_up  = "DATE OF DISCHARGE"
key_low  = "date of discharge"
t1 = "blah blah blah blah DATE OF DISCHARGE more blah blah"
```

Now I am calculating the fuzz ratio of `t1` with `kew_up` and `key_low` as -

```
s9 = fuzz.token_sort_ratio(key_low, t1)
s10 = fuzz.token_sort_ratio(key_up, t1)
```

The problem is I am getting value of 49 in both cases instead of 100 as expected. What is wrong with this approach?

Comment: I'm not extremely familiar with this library, but based on the source and SeatGeek's blog post, it seems like what you're actually looking for is the sorted intersection which means you need to add an argument: partial=True https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy/blob/2188520502b86375cf2610b5100a56935417671f/fuzzywuzzy/fuzz.py#L95

Comment: It is giving error ```token_sort_ratio() got an unexpected keyword argument 'partial'``` @rgk

Comment: The partial version can be used as `partial_token_sort_ratio()`